# Vector input in shiny R and then use it

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny R, I want a simple way to take a vector as user input in ui.R and then want to use that  in a function in server.R.I am new in shiny, please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by vector? Technically almost anything can be considered a vector. Typically people only want vectors of a definite size (or dimension, for example a 3-dimensional vector).

Comment: I want a finite vector input in ui.R (for example: 1,3,5,9) from user and want to use that as an argument of a function in server.R and the dimension of that vector is not fixed.

Comment: Well. Does this answer suit you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is something simple to get you started - good luck. And remember - next time post some code or you will surely get downvoted:

```
library(shiny)

u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Entering Vectors in Shiny"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput('vec1', 'Enter a vector (comma delimited)', "0,1,2")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4('You entered'),
    verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("oid2")
  )
))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$oid1 <- renderPrint({
    cat("As string:\n")
    cat(input$vec1)
    }
    )

  output$oid2<-renderPrint({
    x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$vec1,",")))
    cat("As atomic vector:\n")
    print(x)
  }
  )
}
)
shinyApp(ui = u, server = s)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: yes Mike, it helped and thank you very much for your advice too

Comment: Well, mark it correct then (click on the check on the left side of the top of my answer next to the number :). When you get enough reputation points (15) you can upvote it too if you want.

Comment: to ignore leading and trailing white spaces in the input, you could add `trimws()` around `unlist(strsplit(input$vec1,","))`

Answer (score 6):

I am aware this is an old post but I have come across an alternative way for a user to enter a vector as Shiny input - using the `create = TRUE` and `multiple = TRUE` options with `selectizeInput()`. Slightly modifying Mike Wise's code example from above:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Entering Vectors in Shiny")

    , sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(
        "vec1"
        , "Enter a vector"
        , choices = NULL
        , multiple = TRUE
        , options = list(create = TRUE)
      )

    ),

    mainPanel(

      h4("You entered")

      , verbatimTextOutput("oid1")

      , verbatimTextOutput("oid2")

    )

  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$oid1 <- renderPrint({

    req(input$vec1)

    cat("As string:\n")
    cat(input$vec1)

  })

  output$oid2 <- renderPrint({

    req(input$vec1)

    cat("As atomic vector:\n")
    print(as.numeric(input$vec1))

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Heads up though, this solution does not accept multiple same values (for example, 0.85, 0.92, 0.92 will not work).