# Capture Single Inputs into Vector Output in Shiny R Code

Tags: r, user-interface, vector, colors, shiny

How can I create Vector Output in R Shiny code.

I read this [stackechange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902765/vector-input-in-shiny-r-and-then-use-it), but instead of using textbox, I am using `colourpicker::colourInput`

Working R code is in [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R)

How do I capture the checked boxes and store color values into a vector? If user unchecks a box, the color value should be removed.

Please give hint on doing this.

Below is animated screenshot and the function

[image]

```
CherryPickPalette <- function (name, name2=NULL, name3=NULL){

  if ((nargs() < 2) || (nargs() > 3)){
    stop("Enter 2 or 3 valid palettes. Run ListPalette() for list of palettes.")
  }
  if (nargs() == 2){
    new_pal <- MergePalette(name,name2)
  }
  else if (nargs() == 3){
    new_pal <- MergePalette(name,name2,name3)
  }

  if (interactive()){
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
        sidebarPanel (
          colourpicker::colourInput("col","Choose colors","white", palette="limited", allowedCols = new_pal)),
        mainPanel(
          h5('Your custom colors',style = "font-weight: bold;"),
          fluidRow(column(12,verbatimTextOutput("value"))))
      ),
      server = function(input,output,session){

        output$value<-renderPrint({
          paste(input$col,sep=" ")
        }
        )

      }

    )
  }

}

> CherryPickPalette("Jutti3","Kulfi","Gidha")
```